# Keychain password for macOS Flutter app on VM

Tags: macos, flutter, firebase-authentication, keychain, codemagic

I am using Codemagic macOS remote machine to build and run the Flutter app for macOS. When I try to login into my app with Firebase auth, I get a dialog to enter a keychain password:

[image: keychain dialog]

What password to enter here? If I try to enter a password with which I accessed the virtual machine that's not working. I am building a macOS app in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Enter your password of your mac.